# Can you make the footnote font larger?

Tags: discussion

The footnote font is tiny.  I can read it, but it isn't easy.

In community wiki/furtive's answer to [What is the benefit to telemark skiing?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3341/what-is-the-benefit-to-telemark-skiing) there is an interesting footnote. Maybe it should have been in the main text, but that isn't my point.  If a footnote is worth reading, it should be *easily* readable.

Comment: I  edited it to make it larger. I apologized and asked for it to be rolled back if I shouldn't have done it!

Comment: @Sue it looks much better.  Thanks.

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the footnote and added both the sub/sup markdown so the footnote would be centered. You're right though that in doing so it made the text smaller. I don't have any problem with @Sue's change. More importantly I assume the OP doesn't either since they didn't rollback her and/or my edit. In the future I'll avoid the sub/sup combo and let the content be a touch off center. :)